# Change Pre-selected radio button when loading a page

Tags: javascript, jquery, greasemonkey, userscripts, tampermonkey

I want to apply a script to do some repetitive tasks and change radio buttons from its pre-selected state using tampermonkey.

1) Its pre-selected state:

```
<label for="review_status_pending_*">
 <input type="radio" name="review_status" value="pending" id="review_status_pending_*" checked="checked">
</label>
```

2) The radio button I want it applied

```
<label for="review_status_reviewed_*">
  <input type="radio" name="review_status" value="reviewed" id="review_status_reviewed_*">
</label>
```

Answer (score -2):

You want to uncheck it change its value and change its id?
Really?!? That sounds like absolute madness.

Still you want what you want.

```
var i=document.getElementById('review_status_pending_*');
i.id='review_status_reviewed_*';
i.checked=false;
i.parentNode.setAttribute('for',review_status_reviewed_*)
```

That fact that you don't know how to do this makes me think you might not be aware of the implications for other scripts on the page. Any code that was looking for the radio button by its id will no longer find it. Similar problems might occur involving the its value being changed. Consider whether you might only want to change it from checked to unchecked.